# Question on finding the value of algebraic identity if $a+b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

If $a,b,c\in \Bbb{R}$ and $a+b+c=0$, then evaluate
$$\left(\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{a-b}\right)\left(\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b}+\frac{a-b}{c}\right)$$
I tried using the identity, $$\frac{b-c}{b+c}+\frac{a-c}{a+c}+\frac{a-b}{a+b}=-\frac{b-c}{b+c}\cdot\frac{a-c}{a+c}\cdot\frac{a-b}{a+b}$$However, I couldn't get anywhere. I also tried using normal algebraic methods but I couldn't get anywhere.

Please help me out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: Instead of $a-c$ there should be $c-a$ ... Otherwise you won't be able to prove that.

Comment: Is this question related to contest math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X=\left(\frac{c-a}{b}+\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{a-b}{c}\right) \left(\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{a-b}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{a^3-a^2 (b+c)-a \left(b^2-3 b c+c^2\right)+(b-c)^2 (b+c)}{a b c}=$$
$$=\frac{a^3-a^2 b-a^2 c-a b^2+3 a b c-a c^2+b^3-b^2 c-b c^2+c^3}{a b c}=$$
$$=\frac{(a+b+c)^3-4 (a b+a c+b c) (a+b+c)+9 a b c}{abc}$$
as $a+b+c=0$ we have $X=9$